# how to simulate only the redirect part of hotspot

Tags: networking, router, hotspot

i want to know if is possible, to simulation the little part of hotspot the redirect any http request to the login page, i want it to redirect to my local server apache.Anything user try to acess on web browser instead of return 404 page it send to my local server.( ill not be coonect to internet). lets say you type youtube.com, as im not connect to internet, it will not find the adress and will return 404, but instead i want it to send the request to my apache server.Or a way to the router transform all domains to my local ip(apache server).

Answer (score 0):

You could use "ip route" to redirect traffic from ip A (192.X.X.X) to the interface that's connected to your apache server (eth0):

```
ip route add 192.X.X.X dev eth0
```

or you could use "iptables" to redirect traffic from interface A (eth0) to interface B (eth0):

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

PS: I'm assuming you are using linux.

Comment: im using windows, but i want to know if its possible to do on the router instead of my pc. the hotspot does it, but i want to know the name of the redirect it does before authentificating the user. i will provide content for people that cant afford internet,ill put my on website as portal, but when people connect to the network, they got be redirect to my server, or they just going to get page 404 or i got give them the ip to connect, should be a option on router =(. i need a name for that function so i can research more about it and make it work.

Comment: @DavidAndrade It's called "Captive Portal", you can redirect all traffic sending an HTTP Redirect (HTTP 302) or you can force all unauthenticated users to use your DNS that permits access only to your captive page. Keep in mind that you can't use your consumer grade router. The best way would be to use a Raspberry Pi and redirect all the traffic using that, by doing so you would have perfect control over your network.